# CI/CD pipeline for gupta team developer applications?

Tags: azure-devops, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I am trying to create a build pipeline using yaml files for gupta applications... Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if that is what you mean:

1) Consuming yaml files in gupta I would take a yaml-library written in .NET e.g. https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet and use .NET-Explorer in gupta to make a wrapper .apl and then use the functionality of the yaml library.

2) You can build gupta applications with e.g. a batch script and call cbixx.exe with command line arguments to build the .apd or .exe.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the second answer is more what I am looking for. I have a number of applications written in Team Developer and my goal is to automatically build them on Azure DevOps.

Comment: Go here: https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/Compile_Build  for a list of command line arguments.                                                                                       
And here is a Build wizard tool that does just that :   https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=&file=BuildTool.zip                       Note you'll need to change all references to *.70 ( Team Developer v7 ) to which ever version you are running. Come back if you need help doing that.